# Django sometimes does not cascade on delete

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have the following relevant models

```py
class GameOddORM(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(GameORM, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='odds')
    # ...
    objects = GameOddQuerySet.as_manager()
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['game', ...], name='unique_game_odd_idx')
        ]
        db_table = 'game_odds'


class GameOddDifferenceORM(models.Model):
    game_id = models.BigIntegerField(null=False)
    left_odd = models.ForeignKey(GameOddORM, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='left_odd_diff')
    right_odd = models.ForeignKey(GameOddORM, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='right_odd_diff')
    value = models.FloatField()
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.Index(fields=['game_id'], name='diff_by_game_idx')
        ]
        db_table = 'game_odds_difference'
```

Sometimes calling `GameOddORM.objects.filter(...).delete()` (there are no subqueries) results in the following exception

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1451, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`betsbot_db`.`game_odds_difference`, CONSTRAINT `game_odds_difference_left_odd_id_1043dadb_fk_game_odds_id` FOREIGN KEY (`left_odd_id`) REFERENCES `game_odds` (`id`))')
```

That error is telling me a row of `game_odds` can't be deleted because there is a foreign key in `game_odds_difference` referencing it. Well I set `ON DELETE CASCADE` in `GameOddsDifferenceORM` model, so that error should not happen, in fact it happens just sometimes. That makes me think it's a concurrency issue because `GameOddORM` insertions and deletions are concurrent. Is Django failing to emulate `ON DELETE CASCADE` because after deleting the rows of `game_odds_difference` new rows may be added in between?

The database has no triggers and I am not making raw queries.
I am using Django 2.2.12, mysqlclient 1.4.6, MySQL 8.0.21, InnoDB database engine and Python 3.8.6

Comment: Does your database has any triggers? or did you *manually* delete records?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it has no triggers and I am not doing any SQL raw query.

Comment: Are you sure migrations are up to date?

Comment: @Laggs Yes, `python manage.py showmigrations` shows all are applied and `makemigrations` does not detecs changes.

Comment: Does this only happen when both `left_odd` and `right_odd` reference the same object? I'd also just double check the migrations that you had run and make sure they have the correct cascades in place.

Comment: @Laggs I have not checked it, but the application logic does not allows `left_odd` and `right_odd` to reference the same object.

Comment: I debugged it and so far IntegrityError was not raised, but it randomly raises on production.

Comment: I also checked the migration file that creates the `left_odd` and `right_odd` fields, they are OK "('left_odd', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='left_odd_diff', to='scraper.GameOddORM')),
('right_odd', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='right_odd_diff', to='scraper.GameOddORM'))"
later migrations does not alter these fields neither the model.

Comment: Since I think it's due concurrency issues, I am going to add a lock at application level to remove the concurrency. I am not sure if Django handles these edge cases in the emulation of `ON DELETE CASCADE`.